# Renci.SSHnet.Sftp Timeout error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, sftp

I´m trying to use Renci.SShnet.sftp library to make a connection to a ftp server.
But when I call the sftp.Connect() method I receive the following error message:
"Socket read operation has timed out after 30000 milliseconds.".
I'm using Visual Basic .Net on Visual Studio 2017.

My code is below:

```
Public Function SendFile(ByVal localFilePath As String, ByVal remotePath As String, ByRef errorReturnMessage As String) As Boolean

    errorReturnMessage = ""

    Try
        Dim test As New Renci.SshNet.SftpClient(serverName, portNumber, userName, passWord)
        test.Connect() '<==== ERROR HERE ======
        test.ChangeDirectory(remotePath)

        Dim str As IO.Stream
        str = IO.File.OpenRead(localPathFile)

        Dim result As Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpUploadAsyncResult = test.BeginUploadFile(str, remotePath)

        Do While True
            If result.IsCompleted Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorReturnMessage = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I´m trying to connect to upload a file.
Thanks for any help.

Best regards, 
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for anyone who tryed to help me. 
I know that ftp and sFtp are different. Sorry by my mistake when I wrote the comment in Jul 16 at 11:35. 
But, the solution was to use winSCP API instead of Renci.
This is to much easyer than Renci and works fine. 
Best regards...